# Does a primitive type get boxed when declared as a dynamic

Tags: c#

I'm working on a way to handle parsing strings to types without knowing what types they are being parsed to.  Specifically bools/ints/dates etc.

I am considering using a Dictionary<Type, Func <string,dynamic>> to do this but want to know if there is going to be a boxing/unboxing of the value.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Miles *dynamic* is a trick of the C# compiler. There is no *dynamic* type. It is silently converted to *object*, plus the compiler knows that it has to generate extra code to handle the "dynamic" part. You can see it if you do *typeof(dynamic) == typeof(object)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the value type instances you return from your funcs will be boxed (you effectively have a dictionary that stores `Func<string, object>`s).

When you invoke the func and try to assign it to a variable or pass it into a method, the value will be unboxed and stored in a reference of the appropriate type.